# Django Dev Server Processing The Same Ajax Request Inconsistently

Tags: django, ajax, post, request

I'm submitting a POST using ajax clientside. It works fine whenever all the requests are valid. However, when I send a POST request to an invalid URL, and then follow it up with another POST request, regardless of whether it's valid, Django processes the request in a completely different manner. Before changing some code it was actually causing the server to crash.

Heres what happens in the Django server stdout when I send two invalid requests in a row:

```
Not Found: /profile/add_favorite
[01/Aug/2019 15:42:25] "POST /profile/add_favorite HTTP/1.1" 404 4132
Not Found: /profile/add_favorite
[01/Aug/2019 15:42:30] "title=Video+TitlePOST /profile/add_favorite HTTP/1.1" 404 4178
```

The second request looks ill-formatted, and it's of a different format than the previous request.

The request was sent using basic Ajax:

```
var conf = {
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: {title: "Video Title"},
         headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken},
        } 
$.ajax(conf)
```

And in the dev tools I checked that the requests were the same:

[image: ]]
[image: ]]

That's just the headers but the data is also the same. Anyways, the exact same code was used for both request. This only happens when I send a request to an invalid URL and then send another request after it, and if I reload the page after sending an invalid request and send another request that request will work like it should, but not without returning a messed up response first.

Behold: If I send a post request to an invalid URL and then reload the page in Chrome chrome will not send a valid GET request, instead it sends a request with the same prepended title, the same invalid format!

```
[01/Aug/2019 16:04:03] "title=Video TitleGET / HTTP/1.1" 403 2513
```

Then that's the issue:
Whenever I send an invalid url Ajax request from my browser, the next request to my server will be made invalid in the same way. I feel sure it's not a browser-side issue, because I can send an incorrect request from one window, and then the next request from a different window will be incorrect! This is the screen from that next request:

[image]

The CSRF token shouldn't even matter the first time a site is loaded, making this message nonsensical.

This is obviously an problem of incredible magnitude for my server, as any time a person sends a request to an invalid URL at my server then the next request will not process correctly.

This must be a bug with the Django development server? What could possibly cause this?

Comment: Are you using the dev server for production? Dev server is for testing.

Comment: No, sorry if it sounded that way @y2knoproblem, but I'm worried the bug will remain once I switch to a production server. Starting to think it's a problem with CSRF middleware.